# Windows minimizing on their own?

Tags: macbook-pro, window-manager

I bought an app called "Air Display" which allows me to use my iPad as a second monitor.  I've noticed that while I am on my second monitor whatever is on the other monitor will minimize after about 30 seconds.

Being new to Macs I'm not sure if this is some known behavior or a side effect of the Air Display app.  Is this because of how I have my mac setup?  If so, is there some setting I can change to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an application called "Spirited Away" installed on my mac that was doing this.  Killed the application and the problem stopped happening.